# What ohms value does this resistor have?

Tags: resistors, resistance

I can't figure out which is the first band of this resistor. The resistor is the damaged.

Can someone please help me?

[image]

This is the circuit of an Air-condition.

[image]

Backside

[image]

Comment: Looks brown to me.   You can't just measure the resistance with a meter????

Comment: Use this: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/resistor-color-code-calculator/  From left-to-right I get 54.60 kohm, 1% tolerance. I leave reading right-to-left up to you. Also **measure it**, if it has a very low resistance it could be an inductor (unlikely though). How do you know it is damaged?

Comment: A 1.26 MΩ ±0.5% resistor seems less likely than the 1% tolerance value suggested by Bimpelrekkie.

Comment: The reading i get in DMM is 11.90MOhms. From brown to green its 1.26 MOhms and form green to brown its 54.60 KOhms. I am not sure what is right.

Comment: @DYZAZTR Do you happen to have know the context of how it was used/connected in the circuit? It could provide a clue as to whether 1.26 MOhm or 54.60 kOhm is more plausible.

Comment: If it's a three band value then 12 Mohms seems the lilkely candidate. Yellow and green could be tempco and tolerance.

Comment: *The reading i get in DMM is 11.90MOhms* then it does not appear to be damaged at all. There's another resistor that is identical, also solder that one out and measure it. Still think they are damaged? I highly doubt that they are.

Comment: Both the resistor are showing the same value in metre. But the colour tells the different story. Life is unfair lol

Comment: `"The resistor is the damaged."` I disagree. [This](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/resistor-explosion-consequences-part-destroyed-circuit-board-focus-exploded-86836350.jpg) is a damaged resistor.

Comment: That one of these resistor *bridges across a high-isolation cut* in the PCB suggests that one (or both) are bleed resistors - which often have high values, like 12MEGohms.